# How can I load a module by name instead of id in JSE?

Tags: joomla, joomla-module, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

I wants to load a module by name like `{loadmodule mod_custom, module_name}` instead of id like `{loadmoduleid 96}`.

Can you please suggest where I will get these settings in the JCE Editor so that JCE editor can load modules by name?

Comment: Configuration of software not used for coding isn't really on topic at SO. You might try the Joomla forums or JCE's own forum.

Comment: or even Stack Exchange's exclusive Joomla community would be appropriate :)  Hope to see you at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F#:~:text=you%20could%20load%20a%20,%20in%20your%20text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{loadmodule your_module_name}` instead of `{loadposition}`. IF you are using a single module you can just put the name there or else if you have many types of same module with different names you can try a different variation of `loadmodule` like

```
{loadmodule mod_modulename title}

mod_modulename = your module Type like for joomla login we have mod_login

title = Your module name that you have given for module.
```